# Use context object for React Hook Form based library

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I am consuming a React Hook Form based library in my project.
Basically, this library re-exports most of the react-hook-form based features.

I am using Yup validation library and want to pass context object to my Yup validation from my custom component (ultimately for doing setError based on the passed context object)

I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass this context object and am a bit confused if this library is even supporting the validation's context object
https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#context

Below is some relevant code from the library (if that can help figure out if context object is supported and how that can be passed)

```
import {
  FormContext,
  useForm,
  OnSubmit,
  UseFormOptions,
  FieldValues,
  DeepPartial,
  Mode,
  FormContextValues
} from 'react-hook-form';



const Form = forwardRef(function Form<FormData extends FieldValues>(
  {
    children,
    defaultValues,
    description,
    mode = 'onBlur',
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: onFormSubmit = noop,
    validateCriteriaMode = 'all',
    reValidateMode = 'onChange',
    classes,
    className,
    density,
    displayedNecessity,
    necessityStyle,
    errorStyle,
    fullWidthFields,
    title,
    banner,
    useScrim = true,
    ScrimProps,
    ...rest
  }: FormProps<FormData>,
  ref: Ref<any>
) {

}
```